# Query to concatenate two json arrays in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, json

I have a column with *json* datatype having values like '[1,2,3,4]' and want to add values like '[5,6]' to this json-array. Checked and came across **concatenate operator i.e. ||** . I am trying something like 
`update user_roles set roles = (roles|| '[111]') where id=?1;` . 
Desired result:-'[1,2,3,4,5,6]' 
   Giving below mentioned error: 
Error Code: 3156. Invalid JSON value for CAST to DOUBLE from column roles

Answer (score 0):

From the list of [12.18.4 Functions That Modify JSON Values](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-modification-functions.html)

You can use: `select json_merge_preserve('[1,2,3,4]','[5,6]');`

This will output: `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]`